# Generate CSS from JSF managed bean

Tags: css, jsf, managed-bean, dynamically-generated

I have this CSS code:

```css
td[data-date='2016-03-08']{
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

I want to apply it on several dates that I want to load from a database. All this could happen inside my JSF managed bean where I generate the CSS code.

So my question is, how can I apply the CSS that I'm gonna get from my JSF managed bean?

Comment: I'm not very sure how java is related to css, which is applied to html by browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to print it as body of HTML `<style>` tag which you put in HTML head.

```html
<h:head>
    ...
    <style>#{bean.css}</style>
</h:head>
```