# Change and save css gradients in a JSF application

Tags: jquery, css, jsf

I have made the following chart with specific style to indicate the level of different memory consumption levels. I do it by assigning a gradient to the `background` of the class as follows:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(247,49,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(247,49,0,0.2) 19%,rgba(242,242,0,0.2) 20%,rgba(242,242,0,0.2) 39%,rgba(97,196,25,0.2) 40%,rgba(97,196,25,0.2) 100%);
```

[image: chart]
But now the challenge is that the gradient levels needs to be modified by the user. I have a JSF application and allowed to use jquery and JS of course.

- So I will need to change the two boundary conditions between green-yellow and yellow-red.
- Save the new gradient in the settings so that it gets applied on page refresh.

Is this even possible? Any ideas? Please let me know if I need to share some more information.

Comment: Something like dynamic css? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090096/generate-css-from-jsf-managed-bean

Comment: This looks promising and something I did not think of. I will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks @Kukeltje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .jqplot-series-canvas{
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(247,49,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(247,49,0,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowRedLimit -1}%, rgba(242,242,0,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowRedLimit}%, rgba(242,242,0,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowGreenLimit -1}%, rgba(97,196,25,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowGreenLimit}%, rgba(97,196,25,0.2) 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(247,49,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(247,49,0,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowRedLimit -1}%,rgba(242,242,0,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowRedLimit}%,rgba(242,242,0,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowGreenLimit -1}%,rgba(97,196,25,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowGreenLimit}%,rgba(97,196,25,0.2) 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(247,49,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(247,49,0,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowRedLimit -1}%,rgba(242,242,0,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowRedLimit}%,rgba(242,242,0,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowGreenLimit -1}%,rgba(97,196,25,0.2) #{chartCustomizeBean.yellowGreenLimit}%,rgba(97,196,25,0.2) 100%);
        }
    </style>
```

Thanks to the pointer from @Kukeltje I was able to set up a dynamic gradient, by including the class inside the header of the xhtml page. From a UI form the values can be changed and then on submit I update the page and the new values gets updated. The saved button has been designed like this to reload the page on submit, that updates the gradient values as well.

```
<h:commandButton type="submit"
     styleClass="data-customize" id="data-customize" 
     actionListener="#{chartCustomizeBean.save}"                                                             
     onclick="location.reload(true);"                                                             
     value="Save">
```